# Facebook graph api and newly defined objects and actions : message: "Unknown path components"

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have defined an og name space, og_shamh, and an action "watch" using the FB app editor. I have called a javascript function (below) which attempts to create an action object. But I get :

```
["error response from fbCreateAction", 
Object
error: Object
message: "Unknown path components: /og_shamhh:watch"
type: "OAuthException"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

The javascript function called with "og_shamhh" and "watch" is:

```
function fbCreateAction(action,url){
    FB.api('/me/'+og_namespace+':'+action+
           '?recipe='+url,'post',
           function(response) {
           log("error response from fbCreateAction",response);
               if (!response || response.error) {
                   alert('Error occured');
               } else {
                   alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
               }
           });
}
```

Is there something i need to do on the facebook side that my app can use my actions? I am myself logged in and am an app admin. is this something to do with needing to submit my actions for approval?

You can see the relvant meta data, header etc here : http://www.shamrockirishbar.com/tvsport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved and others now pending. It turns out I had, duh, changed the action name.... Silly

Comment: yes it seems that even if you change the action name, it still expects the original name (as seen in the "Get Code").

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when either the `namespace` or the `action` (or both) in the api url are wrong.

To make sure you access the good url, check the `Get Code` link near the action you want to perform in the `Action Types` section of the `Open Graph` tab of your app's settings.

Alternatively you can check out: `Open Graph` > `Dashboard` > `Your Action Type` > `Advanced Settings` at the bottom of the page.