# Facebook Javascript API unknown path components

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Facebook sharing into a webpage using this code edited from their official developer tutorial, but I'm not having any luck.

```
function postToFacebook(item_id)
{

  FB.api(
    '/me/completeset:display',
    'post',
    { item: 'http://completeset.us/item/'+item_id },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
       } else {
          alert('Share was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    }); //End api
}
```

I've got the app set up, with an "item" object and the "defined" action defined. I haven't been able to submit the action yet though, because I haven't been able to post anything with it yet. I've verified that the item_id is being passed in correctly, and I've debugged the url using their debugging tool. When I call this function I'm getting `unknown path components/ completeset:display`. I haven't been able to find much information on this error, so I'm wondering: what are the causes, and how might I be able to fix it?

Comment: Where did you find the completeset:display path? it is not in the docs as far as i can remember... but maybe im wrong

Comment: completeset is the namespace of my app and display is the action I'm trying to invoke. That is the proper syntax, is it not?

Comment: yes it is... did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286897/facebook-graph-api-and-newly-defined-objects-and-actions-message-unknown-pat

Comment: What do you know, turns out it was a mismatch in the names. No idea why though, I didn't change the action or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names mismatched. The getCode link for the action on facebook displayed the name of the action as being show_off for some reason. It was the same problem as the linked question. I experimented with the app backend and found that if you create an action with one name and then change the name of it, it will display with the new name but you must still reference it using the old name in the code.